# Tool to see network calls made by an Android app

Tags: android, java, security, network-monitor, http

I am trying to search for security vulnerabilities in the Android app and hence wanted to know the software which can help me to track the network calls being by an Android App.

The software should be able to run on Windows 32 bit.

**EDIT:** I want to track the HTTPS calls also, along with the data sent with them so that I can modify the data and resend the call.

Comment: Do you want to see the content of each network call? Do you want to see HTTPS calls too? Are you able to modify the app, or not?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul I want to track HTTPS calls and yes I want to see the content of each network call as I might be requiring to modify the parameters and recall it. I have access to the apk of the app and no access to the source code.